# disable sound level setting

Tags: sound

every time I connect my blue tooth headphones, I have to go into settings, sound, and check "Allow louder than 100% (may distort sound)" setting so that I can turn up the volume more. I end up having to do it a few times a day and wondered if there was any way to disable this feature? I am using ubuntu 16.04.